# My Tesla coil isn't working

Tags: mosfet, batteries, current, circuit-design, tesla-coil

I've pretty much decided to make this mini project in order to get my other classmates more interested into researching electrotechnics, and I've chosen a Tesla coil to be a very cool example of how electrotechnics can be cool and interesting.

I searched up some designs and circuits and came across this schematic on a [Youtube tutorial:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwCWgKdTuI8)

[image]

I have made this circuit, made some 300~ secondary turns with a wire from a transformer I found in a garage (yes I unwound the transformer and had to wind the entire coil by myself,) and after assembling the circuit, I connected two 9 V batteries in a series making them 18 V, and then I connected them to the main circuit.  The only thing happening was the MOSFET heating up.

[image]

[image]

I tried reversing the primary too, but it still didn't work. I tried reversing the resistor, and it didn't work. I'm not sure what's wrong with it, please help and point out wrong things.

Comment: the primary winding wire looks bare ... is it actually insulated?

Comment: oh I haven't actually tought about that, is there a way to check if it is insulated?

Comment: measure resistance

Comment: how exactly do i measure the resistance, i do not have an ohmmeter so?

Comment: use a battery and a lamp ...you really need a DVM ... even a cheap one

Comment: so listen, im gonna order a multimeter, and welp im gonna try measuring the reiststance when it comes most propably tomorrow, just im not  really sure what part of it im supposed to measure specifically

Comment: hey so i've changed up the primary coil with an actually insulated one, the old wire was very poorly insulated and my multimeter showed values between 50-200 ohms, but from some reason it still doesn't work